# I am getting memory exception "System.IO.out of exception" error

Tags: c#

For small directory size code is working fine ,it gives this error message when size of directory files are big.

My code :

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines = 
          Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\watson_query\", "*.*")
                   .Select(filePath => File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
                   .SelectMany(line => line)
                   .Where(line => !line.Contains("appGUID: null"))
                   .ToList();

List<string> users = new List<string>();

textLines.ToList().ForEach(textLine =>
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:\s*(?<username>[^\s]+)");
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(textLine);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var user = match.Groups["username"].Value;
        if (!users.Contains(user)) 
            users.Add(user);
    }
});

int numberOfUsers = users.Count(name => name.Length <= 10);
Console.WriteLine("Unique_Users_Express=" + numberOfUsers);
```

Comment: I am getting readability exception ..

Comment: Have you checked how many lines you are actually processing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use next code, it uses `ReadLines`, which doesn't load entire file into memory, but read file line by line. It also uses `HashSet` to store unique results from matching a regular expression.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:\s*(?<username>[^\s]+)");
IEnumerable<string> textLines = 
      Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\watson_query\", "*.*")
               .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
               .SelectMany(line => line)
               .Where(line => !line.Contains("appGUID: null"));

HashSet<string> users = new HashSet<string>(
    textLines.SelectMany(line => regex.Matches(line).Cast<Match>())
             .Select(match => match.Groups["username"].Value)
);

int numberOfUsers = users.Count(name => name.Length <= 10);
Console.WriteLine("Unique_Users_Express=" + numberOfUsers);
```

Comment: @llya Ivanov :Thanks.I tried your code, it is giving error that "System.IO.File" does not contains a definition for 'ReadLines'

Comment: @HarishBhatia then you probably use **.net** version prior to **4.0**. Do you have possibility to switch to **4.0**? You still can try to use it with `ReadAllLines`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) since they are less memory hungry, they are working like a `StreamReader` whereas `Directory.GetFiles` and `File.ReadAllLines` reads all into memory first:

```
var matchingLines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\watson_query\", "*.*")
    .SelectMany(fn => File.ReadLines(fn))
    .Where(l => l.IndexOf("appGUID: null", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
foreach (var line in matchingLines)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:\s*(?<username>[^\s]+)");
    // etc pp ...
}
```

You also don't need to create the `List<string>` for all the lines again. Just enumerate the query with `foreach`(`textLines.ToList` creates a third collection which is also redundant).